# WP7 Phonegap download xml from cross domain url using YQL

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

the following code works on firefox,chrome and IE9 on my PC.
But the callback function doesn't return when I run it in WP7 device using phonegap.

```
function downloadXML(
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: yql_url('http://some-cross-domain-url'),
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
            navigator.notification.alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
        },
    success: function (xml) {
            navigator.notification.alert("successful");
        }
    });
    }
    yql_url = function(source_url) {
    return "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url=\"" + source_url + "\"";
    }
```

Does anyone point out what EXTRA has to be done to make it run on WP7 ? THX

OR let me re-frame the question,

Can someone give me a code snippet which works on WP7 with phonegap that can fetch XML from a cross domain URL.
I have been trying a lot to make it run on WP7 without any success :(

Comment: There's something odd with your source -- there's a closing brace towards the end that doedn't have a matching opening brace. Is this code complete?

Comment: This *should* work. Perhaps you should try simplifying your code. Can you get a jQuery AJAX request to work for other requests?

Comment: I was able to run the current code on all browsers. Apart from that if I replace dataType from XML to JSONP it works. For some reason in WP7+Phonegap environment the callback function "success" is not reached at all (for xml download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the following to true:

$.support.cors
and
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages

Check the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be similar to [Phonegap for Windows Phone jQuery ajax callback not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031968/phonegap-for-windows-phone-jquery-ajax-callback-not-executed/)

Try the following: comment everything in phonegap-1.3.0.js starting from line 3551 to the end of the file

```
//(function(win,doc){
//
//    doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function()
//    { 
// ......
//      if(!docDomain || docDomain.length == 0)
//      {
//          //console.log("adding our own Local XHR shim ");
//          var aliasXHR = win.XMLHttpRequest;
//      
//          win.XMLHttpRequest = function(){};
//      
//          var UNSENT = 0;
// ......
//
//    
//})(window,document);
```

PS. For XSS on WP7 you also need the following flag for jQuery **$.support.cors = true;**

**EDIT**
PhoneGap 1.4.0rc1 is commited

https://github.com/purplecabbage/callback-windows-phone

Changes include fixes for XHR to local files, + fixes to allow jQM single/multipage apps function correctly.