# Windows phone 7 - no post data for jQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, post, cordova

I'm developing a **PhoneGap** application for Windows Phone 7 and I'm doing some jQuery AJAX calls there. Specifically, I'm sending login POST data to a remote script.

The response is in JSON when our script receive these login credentials in POST data, otherwise it returns HTML of a full login page.

I am quite sure that:

- I've got the *domain whitelisted*
- I've allowed cross-domain requests using *$.support.cors = true* and *$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true*
- it is not an issue with setting *cache: false* (already played around with it)
- passing *data* as JSON object doesn't work either
- playing around with contentType values did not help

When I try POST method, however there are **no post data being transferred to the actual script**.

I have found an [old similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie) which was linked to a desktop Internet Explorer. In my case, however I'm not able to post data at all - not on 1st try, not on 2nd or any other subsequent try.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mypage.com/",
    type: "post",
    data: "login="+$('#login').val()+"&pw="+$('#pw').val(),
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false,
    success: function(loginReturn, status, request) {
            // all ok - we never get here on Windows Phone 7
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, error callback fired and returns "invalid character" parse error, since the expected output it JSON but the whole HTML page is returned instead, as no POST data are found on the server side

Comment: Try to pass data as json object

Comment: didn't help, thanks for the tip though ;-)

Comment: if you on failed login return html obviously you get error on json parse, return a json error object or change dataType

Comment: ok, don't get distracted by what I'm showing when no data is being posted - the problem is POST data is NOT being transferred via AJAX request at all... any idea on that?

Comment: On chrome or ie the code work?

Comment: the issue is only with MSIE being loaded within a PhoneGap application on Windows Phone 7 - testing on standalone MSIE on the phone works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phonegap for Windows Phone jQuery ajax callback not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031968/phonegap-for-windows-phone-jquery-ajax-callback-not-executed)

and

http://shareourideas.com/2012/03/04/phonegap-and-jquery-ajax-call-post-in-windows-phone/

Comment: I've actually stumbled upon those 2 but was too afraid to change it in order to have my PhoneGap upgrade-compatible... well, seems this is the only way to go, thanks!

Comment: just FYI - this does no longer works since approximately PhoneGap 1.7